# Deleting multiple items by index in Flutter Hive

Tags: flutter, cart, flutter-hive

i'm building a cart with flutter hive.
i want to select multiple items and delete then from cart using index! as there could be 2 items with the same title but different sizes or quantities.
Hive doesn't provide a method for that.. only deleteAll() that accepts multiple keys not indexes.

i stored the selected indexes in a List but when i tried to use for loop to delete them it didn't work as the index change after every delete operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that hive itself first gets the key for the item at *index* and then uses the `delete()` function when calling `deleteAt()`

So, one potential solution, compared to looping would be to loop over all of your indices, using `box.keyAt()` to get the keys for each one of the indices, and then using `box.deleteAll()` to remove the items.

Example:

```dart
// Indices to Remove
List<int> indices = [5, 7, 8, 12];

// List to stores keys to remove
List<dynamic> toRemove = [];

// Get all keys from indices
for (int i in indices) {
    toRemove.append(box.keyAt(i));
}

// Remove all keys from box
box.deleteAll(toRemove);
```

However, looping over `removeAt()` seems to be the simplest solution (remember to go from greatest index to least, not the other way, otherwise you will delete the wrong data).

I will make a PR with a fix in a couple hours so that you can run something like `removeIndices()` to remove a list of indices. If you have a better name please let me know by replying.

Comment: Thanks alot for this helpful answer.
However i don't understand the first 2 lines what should I search for to learn about them?
And for the name it could be deleteAllAt

Comment: I've made a [pull request](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/pull/1227) for the `deleteAllAt()` function.